# Kafka installation with Confluent vs Apache Kafka

Tags: kafka

for now we have HDP 2.6.5 version , with Kafka cluster with Kafka version 0.1

all Kafka machines are installed on RHEL version 7.6

all machines with RHEL 7.6 are on DELL physical machines

we want to move to Apache Kafka or Confluent Platform

The Kafka that we need to use is for production , so we intend to install 5 Kafka machines

Now the big Question is:

What is better to use - Apache Kafka or Confluent Platform for production ?